# jquery mouse over

Tags: jquery

In Jquery is there a way to stop the `mouseout()` function from stop activating when you go over a certain `div` it isn't a child either. My html code.

```
 <div class="featured">
            <div class="featured_top">
                    <p><span class="theme">Theme</span> Transparent </p>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="pic" style="background: blue">
                <!-- image -->                              
            </div>
            <div class="featured_des">
                <p> this is awesome theme </p>
            </div>                                  
  </div>
```

my js(jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".pic").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: 0                        
            });
        });

        $(".pic").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: 214                      
            });

             });
       });
```

**So my question** is can you stop the `mouseout()` function from activating when it is `featured_des` div. atm it animates the width of the `.pic` class which works fine but when it finishes `animate` the cursor is over the `featured_des` which activates the `mouseout` and hides the description again

**example::** http://www.grubber.co.nz/developer/_social_development/market.html

Comment: What do you mean by stop it when "it is featured_des div"?

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: @j08691 when the cursor is over the div class named `featured_des`

Comment: @ryanc1256 : The example is all the more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an wrapper around your `pic` and `featured_des`.

```
    <div class="picwrapper">
        <div class="pic" style="background: blue">
            <!-- image -->                              
        </div>
        <div class="featured_des">
            <p> this is awesome theme </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then JS:

```
$('.picwrapper').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.pic').animate({ width: 0 });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.pic').animate({ width: 214 });
});
```

Comment: yer that's what I was thinking of doing, it would make it simpler :-D

Answer (score 0):

'mouseout' will fire when the mouse leaves a particular element..regardless of what causes it to leave. In your case, the re-sizing makes pic too small for the mouse to be over it anymore.

Modify your HTML to enclose both the Feature Description and Pic in a div classed as 'container' so that the object your hovering over doesn't go away causing a mouseout.

```
<div class="featured">
        <div class="featured_top">
                <p><span class="theme">Theme</span> Transparent </p>                                        
        </div>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="pic" style="background: blue">
                 <!-- image -->                              
             </div>
             <div class="featured_des">
                 <p> this is awesome theme </p>
             </div>                 
        </div>                 
</div>
```

And your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".container").mouseover(function(){
          $(this).find('.pic').animate({
                 width: 0                        
          });
      });

      $(".container").mouseout(function(){
          $(this).find('.pic').animate({
                 width: 214                      
          });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so the events don't bubble up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pic").width($(".pic .container img").width());
    $(".pic").height($(".pic .container img").height());
    $(".pic").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".pic .container").animate({
            width: 0
        }, function() { $(".pic .container img").hide(); });
    });

    $(".pic").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".pic .container img").show();
        $(".pic .container").animate({
            width: 214
        });

    });
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vseXP/).